# HTML center element in table without overlay

Tags: html, css, center

I'm making a website, and it has several tables of information, I want these to be next to each other, but I want them to be centered, and not

```
float: left;
```

It should be like centered text: if it leaves the text container, it should go into a new line.

I tried

```
margin: auto;
```

but that puts the elements under each other, but I want them to be next to each other, and go into a new "line", if they leave the div, they are in.

Comment: Have you considered simply using `<center>` tag ?

Comment: You need to provide the code that you use.

Comment: Please share your code, so we can help you to improve the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flexbox

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.table {
  padding: 1em;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">Table 1</div>
  <div class="table">Table 2</div>
  <div class="table">Table 3</div>
  <div class="table">Table 4</div>
  <div class="table">Table 5</div>
  <div class="table">Table 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost what I want to achieve, but when I have enough tables, and they go out of the div, they don't go below, but rather need to be scrolled to.

Comment: I have added flex-wrap. It will now move to the next line when it doesn't fit anymore.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for helping and informing me about this feature!